# Speed up finding devices connected to a Wifi network and get device name

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I'm writing a Java program that will show the names and IP addresses of the devices connected to my Wifi network.

I've figured out the IP address part. Here's the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    // this code assumes IPv4 is used   
    byte[] ip = localhost.getAddress();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 254; i++) {
        ip[3] = (byte) i;
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
        if (address.isReachable(1000)) {
            // machine is turned on and can be pinged
            System.out.println(address + "is online");
        } else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName())) {
            // machine is known in a DNS lookup
            System.out.println(address + "is in a DNS lookup");
        } else {
            // the host address and host name are equal, meaning the host name could not be resolved
            System.out.println(address + " is not online");
        }
    }
}
```

This code works and it shows the IP addresses of the connected devices. 
But there are two problems that I'm facing:

1. I'm not able to get the connected device's name. I can only get the IP address.
2. This program works really slow. It takes 254 seconds to complete.

So how do I display the name of the connected devices and is there any way to speed this program up?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You are assuming that your network is a /24 network. There could be more than 254 nodes connected to your WiFi network, depending on the subnet mask.

Comment: Is BruceWayne's advice working to get device's name?

Comment: @afzalex Nope. It didn't work. Do you know a way to get the device name? Please help me out!

Answer (score 4):

Lowering the timeout value is one way to speed up the discovery process, but with Java 8 came parallel streams.  With parallel streams you can discover remote network devices in parallel rather than sequential, and its the sequential process that eats up your time.

Here's how I would try using parallel streams to discover network devices.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    byte[] localHostIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress();
    List<DiscoverNetworkDevice> networkDevices = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
        // Assuming IPV4
        localHostIp[3] = (byte) i;
        networkDevices.add(new DiscoverNetworkDevice(
                InetAddress.getByAddress(localHostIp).getHostAddress()));
    }

    discover(networkDevices);
    parallelDiscover(networkDevices);
}

public static void discover(List<DiscoverNetworkDevice> networkDevices) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Object[] discoveredDevices = networkDevices
            .stream()
            .filter(nd -> nd.Discover()).toArray();
    for (Object obj : discoveredDevices) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Elapsed: " + (end - start));
    System.out.println();
}

public static void parallelDiscover(List<DiscoverNetworkDevice> networkDevices) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Object[] discoveredDevices = networkDevices
            .parallelStream()
            .filter(nd -> nd.Discover()).toArray();
    for (Object obj : discoveredDevices) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Elapsed: " + (end - start));
    System.out.println();
}

public static class DiscoverNetworkDevice {
    private String hostIp;
    private String hostName;

    public DiscoverNetworkDevice(String hostIp) {
        this.hostIp = hostIp;
    }

    public boolean Discover() {
        try {
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(hostIp);
            if (host.isReachable(500)) {
                hostName = host.getHostName();
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("IP: %s \t Name: %s", hostIp, hostName);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
IP: 192.168.1.1      Name: 192.168.1.1
IP: 192.168.1.121    Name: 192.168.1.121
IP: 192.168.1.137    Name: 192.168.1.137
Elapsed: 126523

IP: 192.168.1.1      Name: 192.168.1.1
IP: 192.168.1.121    Name: 192.168.1.121
IP: 192.168.1.137    Name: 192.168.1.137
Elapsed: 16113
```

As you can see, using parallel streams make a pretty significant difference as far as processing time.

As far as the name being the IP address again, see [InetAddress Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) particularly

[image]

Comment: It will only spawn the number of threads calculated as optimal for the machine. E.g. on my laptop it will first run 4 threads to check 4 IPs, than another 4, another and another... up to 255 in total. And it will be faster than synchronic operation, tho it still waste a lot of time waiting (idle) for multile times. Is there a way to spawn and start all threads at +/- same time, instead of "batch wait" by few of them at a time?

Answer (score 2):

> *This program works really slow. It takes 254 seconds to complete.*

I think I know why. From the [InetAddress documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)):

```
public boolean isReachable(int timeout)
                throws IOException
```

> The timeout value, in milliseconds, indicates the **maximum amount of time the try should take**. If the operation times out before getting an answer, the host is deemed unreachable. A negative value will result in an IllegalArgumentException being thrown.

Therein lies your problem. If you allocate a second as your `timeout` value, your program will take 254 seconds to complete if all hosts were unreachable. Try reducing it.

Comment: Thank you! I reduced the timeout value from 1000 to 100 and from 254 to 20. It works real fast now! Can you please help me get the name of the device?

Comment: @ChinmayDabke, I would think that either [`getHostName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName()) or [`getCanonicalHostName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName()) would do the trick.

Comment: I tried both the suggestions. None of them worked. It just showed me the IP address again and not the name of the device. Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Maybe it's too late to put an answer put I was searching on a solution for the same problem and maybe my answer would be useful for other 
I think that the scanners program use the multi threading for speed up the search 
and it's really effective that's my code

```
public class NetLimiter {

public interface DiscoverDeviceEeventListener extends EventListener {
    public void discovered(Device device);
    public void failed(Device device);
}

DiscoverDeviceEeventListener discoverDeviceEventHandler = null;

public void setDiscoverDeviceEvent(DiscoverDeviceEeventListener handler) {
    this.discoverDeviceEventHandler = handler;
}

public class Device {

    private String hostIp;
    private String hostName;

    public Device(String hostIp) {

        this.hostIp = hostIp;
        EventListenerList l = new EventListenerList();

    }

    public boolean discover() {
        try {
            InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(hostIp);
            if (host.isReachable(1000)) {
                hostName = host.getHostName();
                if (discoverDeviceEventHandler != null) {
                    discoverDeviceEventHandler.discovered(this);
                }
                return true;
            } else if (discoverDeviceEventHandler != null) {
                discoverDeviceEventHandler.failed(this);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.print(ioe);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("IP: %s \t Name: %s", hostIp, hostName);
    }
}

String subnet = "";

public NetLimiter(String subnet) {
    this.subnet = subnet;
}

public void checkDevices() {

    for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
        String host = subnet + "." + i;
        (new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                     (new Device(host)).discover();
            }
        }).start();

    }

}



}
```

maybe it's harmful to generate 253 thread but splitting them to multi threads like each 10 of them in one thread it will effectively speed up the process